# Building a VGA circuit

Tags: microcontroller, dac, vga, image-sensor

I am building an 8 bit VGA circuit and have 3 choices. One is to use a simple resistor network to convert digital to analog. The second is to use an op-amp. The third way to do this is to use a device like this [CS4344](https://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/CS4344-45-48_F2.pdf). (This isn't suitable because of the frequency, but I am still looking for a low cost DAC.) I am looking for a cost effective but accurate way to do this. I know the pure resistor solution is probably the cheapest but the issue is it requires a lot of digital pins. However with a serial DAC I can use fewer pins. The data rate will be about 24Mhz at 30fps (it will be 640x480 resolution.) What is a good way to do this?

If I just use resistors in parallel, how do I impedance match for 75 ohm? Is this necessary or is it not needed?

Comment: What are you driving it from? There are some PIC24 parts that have a nice set of 3 fast DACs built in for doing this. (PIC24FJ256DA206 - See http://store.hackaday.com/products/layerone-demoscene-board )

Comment: A spartan 6 FPGA

Comment: if  I just use plain resistors is impendace mataching important?

Comment: Variable Gain Amplifier?

Comment: I want to use as few component as possible on the board since I will be assembling these at home. SO adding opamps actually means quite a bit of extra work. What I am asking is I see a lot of VGA being driven just using resistances. Is it needed for me to use the opamp?

Comment: @red-car I am not sure why would you need opamps, but if you want just some buffering, an emitter follower, with a 75 Ohm resistor in the emitter will do.

Comment: Plain resistors will have a high (and varying!) output impedance, so you can't really match it. On the other hand for normal length VGA cables it shouldn't matter too much, it'll terminate at the far end. Is your 8 bit video RRRGGGBB or 8 bits per channel (24 bit) - the latter is going to be quite hard to get completely right with resistors only.

Comment: Its a total of 8bit VGA.

Comment: @ilkhd and pjc50 are both correct here. Just sending a R/2R resistor DAC signal out will produce many different impedances. So use op-amp buffers or emitter-followers on the R2R outputs, designed with 75Ω impedance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a look in the [Basys2 manual](https://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/BASYS2/Basys2_rm.pdf) (p.8, Fig 13) how it is done there.
(The Basys2 board is a starter kit for the Spartan 3):

[image]

For simple applications with only 3bits for R and G and 2bits for B a simple resistor network seems to be good enough.

BTW: I don't understand your concern about "require[ing] lot of digital pins" when your FPGA has probably more then hundred digital IOs.

Comment: It depends on the package. Soldernig BGA at home for a project is not easy.

Comment: In that case I recommand to use a different package (if available) or a BGA breakout board that gives easy access to all pins.

Comment: Doesnt it need to be terminated in 75 ohm?

Comment: @redcar - It will be terminated in 75 ohms at the monitor.

Comment: @redcar: ideally yes, but it probably won't hurt if it is more. Maybe the signal edges won't be as clean as they could be but for an intensity resolution of max. 3bits per color it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

An external serial DAC is a monumentally bad proposition. The reason is I/O speed. At 24 MHz pixel rate, the DAC must be fed at a minimum $$f_{min} = 24 \text{ MHz} \times 8 = 192 \text{ MHz}$$ While the Spartan 6 is perfectly happy doing this, your external DACs (and you need 3 of them) will apparently be kluged in, and I don't like to think about how that will work.

Comment: Yes. I agree. High-end DAC's are very expensive also. THe other is video encoders, but once agin the cost is a bit too steep for this application